# Qt 5.6 on windows compilier error

Tags: qtquick2, qt3d, qt5.6

I'm starting out with QT creator

My objective is to use it to create a Application using Qt3D and QT quick Ui

When I try to create a project it shows me I don't have a compiler yet: (screenshot on link)

[QT new project, no compiler error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J9RXW.png)

If I try to build an example it shows me the following error:

16:35:11: Configuration is faulty. Check the Issues view for details.
Error while building/deploying project shadow-map-qml (kit: Desktop Qt 5.6.0 MSVC2015 64bit)
When executing step "Make"

Did I do something wrong on the installation or Do I need to download and install a separate compiler? If so for Qt 5.6 on windows 10 which should I download?

Comment: Do you have Visual C++ installed? If yes so you need to set it up on the `Compilers` tab in `Options/Build and Run`. If no so you have to install it (there is some free version I think) or download and install MinGW with GCC compiler

Comment: Thanks, I downloaded the  QT 32bit option which comes with MinGW